# Comparing log with rationals

Tags: logarithms, number-comparison

So I came across with this problem: To prove $\log_27<2\sqrt3$. This is not difficult as LHS$<3<$RHS.

However, I did want to know how to generalise the solution. In particular, given integers $M,N$, how can we prove a rational number $r=\frac pq$ that is greater than $\log_MN\,?$

An attempt I tried is to generate a sequence of rationals that converges to $\log_MN$, however, that did not go very well for me.

Thank you.

Comment: Kurt, what did you try ? Please, write your efforts and attempts if you want us to help you.

Comment: See, [Shank's algorithm](https://exstrom.com/blog/abrazolica/posts/logarithm.html). Truncate the continued fraction (stop the algorithm) after some even number of steps (the truncations of the continued fraction alternate being smaller and larger than the limit) and you get rational numbers above the log getting closer and closer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
    \log_MN<\frac{p}{q}
    \iff N^q<M^p.
$$
So, the question is equivalent to computing powers of integers.

**Ex.**

$$
    8=2^3<3^2=9
    \implies \log_{3}{2}<\frac{2}{3}
$$

One can get rational approximations of $\log_MN$ by a variant of Euclid's algorithm. Start with $M$ and $N$ and repeatedly divide the larger number by the smaller one until the numbers become close to $1$. This gives something of the form $M^pN^{-q}\approx 1$. Then $\log_MN\approx \frac{p}{q}$.

**Ex.**

\begin{align*}
    2,\quad &3\\
    3/2,\quad &2\\
    3/2,\quad &2^2/3\\
    3^2/2^3,\quad &2^2/3\\
    3^2/2^3,\quad &2^8/3^5\\
    \vdots
\end{align*}

and these give rational approximations to $\log_32$

\begin{align*}
    0,\quad &1/0\\
    1,\quad &0\\
    1,\quad &1/2\\
    2/3,\quad &1/2\\
    2/3,\quad &5/8\\
    \vdots
\end{align*}
The last approximation $0.625$ is close to the true value $0.6309$.